# Cannot plot MACD with Date as index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am a beginner at Python and I am trying to learn how to plot MACD with Signal line. I have a CSV with columns such as 'Date', 'Close', and so forth. I would like the Date to be the index.

The Date is in the following format: 02/08/20 20:18

So if I don't make the Date the index and I plot it, the graph shows up fine and it looks normal. This is the code I'm using to show the Close Price and the Date:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
plt.plot(df['Close'], label='Close')
plt.title('Close Price History')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price USD ($)')
plt.show
```

However, if I use the following code to "standardize" the Date:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.floor('d')
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'].values))
```

And then use the first code to plot the graph, it shows up extremely messy and all over the place.

Could someone please help me make the 'Date' column the index without ruining my graph and computations?

Thank you very much!

Comment: provide format in `to_datetime` function according to your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

Here's a small dataframe as an example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["02/09/20 20:18", "02/10/20 20:18", "02/11/20 20:18", 
                           "02/12/20 20:18", "02/13/20 20:18", "02/14/20 20:18"],
                   "Close":[20, 40, 50, 25, 80, 30]})
```

You can then set the index and plot as follows:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df = df.set_index("Date")

plt.plot(df.index, df["Close"])
plt.show()
```

[image]